# how to install phpmyadmin in Ubuntu server 18.04.1 LTS Bionic?

Tags: 18.04, phpmyadmin

i created this question because i cant install phpmyadmin in Ubuntu 18.04 bionic LTS.

i use

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

And get "unable to locate package"

I search the package in `package.ubuntu.com`

And add to sources.list this repository:

```
mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu
```

Now appear a error from depencies.

```
php-mbstring
php-common
```

later when try install these, appear:

```
php7.2-mbstring
php7.2-common
```

And later:

```
0.7.2ubuntu-0 (something like this)
```

How can i install phpmyadmin?

### I do this

```
sudo apt-get update
```

*all packages are updated*

> sudo apt-get upgrade

*0 updated, 0 new will by installed, 0 for delete and 0 not updated*

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

*reading package list... done
creating three of dependencies
reading state information... done
E: cannot locate package phpmyadmin*

Comment: Please add `sudo` to your commands

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen i do it with root user, and adding sudo

Comment: Please don't do it with root user rather add `sudo`!

Comment: Please update your repo and try again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

After check

```
apt search phpmyadmin
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
adminer/bionic 4.6.2-1 all
  Web-based database administration tool

phpliteadmin/bionic-security,bionic-updates 1.9.7.1-1ubuntu0.1 all
  web-based SQLite database admin tool

phpliteadmin-themes/bionic-security,bionic-updates 1.9.7.1-1ubuntu0.1 all
  web-based SQLite database admin tool - themes

phpmyadmin/bionic 4:4.6.6-5 all
  MySQL web administration tool
```

After install

```
sudo apt install phpmyadmin
...
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils dbconfig-common dbconfig-mysql javascript-common libapache2-mod-php7.2 libapr1 libaprutil1
  libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libjs-jquery libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore liblua5.2-0 libsodium23 libzip4 php php-bz2 php-pear
  php-php-gettext php-phpseclib php-tcpdf php-zip php7.2 php7.2-bz2 php7.2-cli php7.2-common php7.2-json php7.2-opcache php7.2-readline php7.2-zip
Suggested packages:
  www-browser apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine | apache2-suexec-custom php-libsodium php-mcrypt php-gmp php-imagick
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data apache2-utils dbconfig-common dbconfig-mysql javascript-common libapache2-mod-php7.2 libapr1 libaprutil1
  libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 libaprutil1-ldap libjs-jquery libjs-sphinxdoc libjs-underscore liblua5.2-0 libsodium23 libzip4 php php-bz2 php-pear
  php-php-gettext php-phpseclib php-tcpdf php-zip php7.2 php7.2-bz2 php7.2-cli php7.2-common php7.2-json php7.2-opcache php7.2-readline php7.2-zip
  phpmyadmin
0 upgraded, 34 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 18.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 75.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

Comment: Along that i used:

`apt-get autoclean later
apt-get autoremove later
apt-get update later
apt-get upgrade later`

Comment: I LOVE YOU <3 jajajaja

Answer (score 1):

You can install `phpMyAdmin` from the default `Ubuntu` repositories

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install phpmyadmin php-mbstring php-gettext
```

This [article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-18-04) is clear enough.

Comment: i got in the repositories: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic . but dont work

Comment: where you get the repository ?

Comment: default installation, where i can find the most actual repository?

Comment: https://ibb.co/kk7Loz

Comment: Bionic has  a repo for it do `apt search phpmyadmin`

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen nothing appear

Comment: `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` worked fine to me, can you post each step with the output?

Comment: @JohnJoe i will do, but the output is in spanish

Comment: I have more information to add related to this problem but it does not fit in the form of a comment. How can I supply it?

Comment: you can edit your post

Answer (score 1):

You can install `phpMyAdmin` from the [mirror_kernel](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/phpmyadmin/download) for bionic Ubuntu repositories

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install phpmyadmin*
```

if you said nothing appear to do `apt search phpmyadmin`
please check your repo with right repo in that link.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is as follows (in case the link goes dead [good point, Melebius]):

*You should be able to use any of the listed mirrors by adding a line to your /etc/apt/sources.list like this:

deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe

Replacing cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu with the mirror in question.

You can download the requested file from the pool/universe/p/phpmyadmin/ subdirectory at any of these sites:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/all/phpmyadmin/download

> You should be able to use any of the listed mirrors by adding a line
>   to your /etc/apt/sources.list like this:
>
> ```
> deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe
> ```
>
> Replacing `cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` with the mirror in question.
>
> You can download the requested file from the
>   `pool/universe/p/phpmyadmin/` subdirectory at any of these sites:
>
> North America
>
> - mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu
> - ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ubuntu
> - lug.mtu.edu/ubuntu
> - ubuntu.mirrors.tds.net/ubuntu
> - ubuntu.secs.oakland.edu
> - mirror.mcs.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu
> - mirrors.cat.pdx.edu/ubuntu
> - ubuntu.cs.utah.edu/ubuntu
> - ftp.ussg.iu.edu/linux/ubuntu
> - mirrors.xmission.com/ubuntu
> - mirrors.cs.wmich.edu/ubuntu
> - gulus.USherbrooke.ca/pub/distro/ubuntu
>
> Asia
>
> - kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> - th.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> - mirror.lupaworld.com/ubuntu
> - kambing.vlsm.org/ubuntu
> - ubuntu.mithril-linux.org/archives
> - mirror.in.th/ubuntu
> - mirror.rootguide.org/ubuntu
>
> Africa
>
> - za.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
>
> Europe
>
> - cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> - de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> - dk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> - es.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> - fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> - ge.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> - gr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> - hr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> - mt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> - nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> - no.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> - se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> - yu.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> - nz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> - nz2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> - ftp.iinet.net.au/pub/ubuntu
> - mirror.optus.net/ubuntu
> - ftp.filearena.net/pub/ubuntu
> - mirror.pacific.net.au/linux/ubuntu

Comment: Ah, good point.